# Asp.Net Core 3.0 API app requires restart frequently on IIS Windows Server 2016

Tags: asp.net-core

I have hosted my Asp.Net Core API project on IIS on Windows Server 2016 and also installed hosting bundle for Asp.Net core apps on that; have to restart my application after few hours. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: what do you mean by restart? your IIS got restarted or Application got restarted? what is the frequence? where did you see the restart, from event viewer or somewhere else? is this restart caused from a crash?

Comment: restart means.. my API is serving data to the mobile application and during a day when user request for data from mobile app, after few hours of continuous request-response cycle, API stops responding; to enable it to respond on an HTTP request, I have to stop and start my API app from IIS.

Comment: This may caused by a varity of possiable reason, you need to capture a dump file while the API stops responding and analysis if there is any thing hanging there in your code. I've once see the same issue and it turns out in my code my redis connection is injected by DI and with a wrong scope evey request opened a new connection and finally my port is running out. So it is case by case. You can use [DebugDiag](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924) tool to capture a dump and analysis it.

Comment: you can refer to below documents to capture a dump file when your application hang. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/919792/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-a-process-that-h

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem? Is there any error message? You need to be more specific on your issue.

Comment: restart means.. my API is serving data to the mobile application and during a day when user request for data from mobile app, after few hours of continuous request-response cycle, API stops responding; to enable it to respond on an HTTP request, I have to stop and start my API app from IIS.